# When is it better to lazy load instead of eager load with EF 4.1 DbContext (+ SQL 2008 R2)?

Tags: performance, entity-framework-4.1, sql-server-2008-r2, guid, dbcontext

I know the answer is "it depends". I'm finding with some operations that removing the eager-loading is actually improving performance, both on my LM and on AppHarbor (still not yet tested on Azure).

In the cases I have tried so far, the root entity is not being queried by its primary key. The primary key is an int, but these queries go against Guid candidate keys to obfuscate the int pk from URL's. I do not have a key or index on the Guid, the only key (other than fk's) is the int pk, and it is clustered.

Might eager loading be faster with a non-clustered index on the Guid candidate key?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to weigh cost of executing many small queries vs one big query. And also if you need all the related data and are planning to process all the data immediately after receiving it then lazy loading may not be great idea.

Also, take a look at these two articles on the topic written by Julie Lermann:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh205756.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg309181.aspx